# Regex matching url authority parts

Tags: c++, regex, url, boost-regex, authority

I need to match these parts of the following string:

```
(user)@(hostname):(port)
```

User and port can optionally be matched.
First I managed it with this regular expression:

```
(?:([^@]*)@)?([^\:]+)(?:\:(\d+))?
```

This matches for `foo@bar:80`

```
foo
bar
80
```

But when it comes to a IPv6 host like `foo@[2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344]:80`, the preceding regex won't work as expected:

```
foo
[2001
0
```

So now I'm pondering about a regular expression which can also match square bracket enclosed hosts with colons, but without square brackets. :)
I've done that with the following regex:

```
(?:([^@]*)@)(?:\[(.+)\]|([^:]+))(?:\:(\d+))?

foo
2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344
<empty>
80
```

But.. this is ugly, because either `2` or `3` will be empty.
Is there any way to combine this to only one backreference?

I'm using boost::regex, which uses perl's regex engine as far as I know.

Thanks and regards

reeaal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?:([^@]*)@)(\[.+\]|([^:]+))(?:\:(\d+))?
```

But you'll have to strip off the `[]` if it's an IPv6 addr. Should be fairly trivial though.

You could also do it with optional `[` and `]` before and after, and then lookaround assertions... but that's REALLY ugly; your fellow programmers will thank you if you just KISS and use the above, but here's the option:

```
(?:([^@]*)@)\[?((?<=\[).+(?=\])|([^:]+))\]?(?:\:(\d+))?
```

Comment: Thanks. If there is no other way, I will do it like so. But I hope someone has a crazy idea. :)

Comment: Well, the other way to do it would be to put `[?` and `]?` outside the capture, and then put zero-width lookbehind and lookahead assertions inside the query. One moment and I'll add that example.

Comment: Ok, persuaded. :) I'll use the above.